# what are emacs' keybindings in sharelatex?

Tags: sharelatex

I've just signed up to Sharelatex.com, the free latex online editor. I've noticed there's the possibility to choose keybindings among Vim, emacs or *none*. I've chosen the emacs key-bindings but no environment opens when I press C-c e (that is Ctrl, 'c' and then 'e'), why is that? What are key-bindings then? Has anyone tried this feature of sharelatex? Can you please help me out, here? (I'm on Chrome Browser running on 32-bit Windows 7 and  Colemak keyboard layout instead of QWERTY, but I doubt this interferes with said feature)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use sharelatex, but does it work if you enter `C-c C-e`?

Comment: I tried – no results, although copy/pasting works as in EMACS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used many different online editors for various things that claim to have emacs keybindings (including ShareLaTeX and Overleaf). This 'feature' boils down to (a pathetic subset of) the movement commands *only*: `C-[npfbae]` (and sometimes) `M-[<>]` and `C-s`. Some basic editing commands are also sometimes available: `C-[tdiomyw]` and `M-w`. The stuff that makes emacs great is in emacs.

The functionality you're looking for simply does not exist outside emacs.

Comment: Also, even the C-n command does not work on chrome. It always opens a new window and is non-overridable.

Comment: How do you work around the fact that KILL, ctrl + w closes the pane?

Comment: Have a look at [conkeror](http://conkeror.org/).  It's a browser that in inspired by emacs. You can add your own key bindings as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid browser keystroke conflicts (with c-n, c-w, etc.) by creating a desktop shortcut in Google Chrome. Navigate to ShareLaTeX or Overleaf and then click the three dots in the top right hand corner of Chrome. Then go to "More tools" and then "Create Shortcut." Make sure to check the box that says "Open in new window." This will create a shortcut on your desktop that will open up ShareLaTeX or Overleaf. If you double click on this, it will open the site in a new window and all of the keystrokes (including c-n and c-w) will work properly. You can pin this shortcut to your taskbar or move it wherever you like.

If you use Linux, your other option would be to use the Emacs gtk theme. You can set this up by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124815/how-do-i-enable-emacs-keybindings-in-apps-such-as-google-chrome/918962#918962). This will stop keystroke conflicts with Chrome and ShareLaTeX/Overleaf's Emacs mode.

Overleaf has [a page](https://www.overleaf.com/help/66-which-emacs-commands-are-usable-in-emacs-mode) that mentions conflicts with browser keystrokes for users of their Emacs mode. Their two suggestions are either using a Firefox plugin or a Mac. Unfortunately, the Firefox plugin only works in older versions of Firefox that are no longer supported, so you don't want to install them on your computer.

Comment: @TeXnician aren't they merging?

Comment: My answer also applies to ShareLaTeX. Overleaf posted information about this issue. But the issue and information about it are the same for both services.

Comment: @daleif Didn't know that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Finally CTRL c and CTRL w keybindigs for emacs worked in overleaf using the chrome by creating a shortcut on my desktop as suggested by @akindofyoga.
Thanks